# Qt - The compiler may not produce code compatible with the Qt version

Tags: qt, qt-creator, mingw-w64, msys2, qt6

I use MSYS2 on Windows 10 and have installed Qt 6.2.0 and Qt Creator 5.0.2.
Then I set up Qt Kit and see this warning:

[Qt Kits warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA4KI.png)

> Warning: The compiler "MinGW-w64 MINGW64 C++ (MSYS2)" (x86-windows-msys-pe-64bit)
> may not produce code compatible with the Qt version "Qt 6.2.0 (mingw64)"
> (x86-windows-msys-pe-64bit).

How to address this issue?

I use MINGW64 subsystem of MSYS2 that has following related packages installed:

```
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc 11.2.0-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb 11.1-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-qt-creator 5.0.2-2
mingw-w64-x86_64-qt6-* 6.2.0-2
```

I failed to figure out toolchain version that was used to build Qt6 packages in order to provide the same toolchain for building applications. The only information I got is `ABI : x86-windows-msys-pe-64bit` and `QT_VERSION : 6.2.0`.

Warning message says both compiler and Qt have similar `x86-windows-msys-pe-64bit` ABI, but it seems to be insufficient.

Until this point I successfully build, run and debug code, but still would like to get rid of this warning if it makes sense.

Comment: In the qt installation directory should be a `mkspecs/qconfig.pri` file, which contains the used compiler version (`QT_GCC_MAJOR_VERSION`, `QT_GCC_MINOR_VERSION`, `QT_GCC_PATCH_VERSION`).

Comment: @ssbssa Thanks for the hint! I've found out my Qt 6.2.0 was built with GCC 10.3.0 and I'm pretty sure I've seen this warning when I had the same GCC on my MSYS2 system. Nonetheless, I'll try to provide Qt Creator with the same GCC Qt has and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this warning goes away when GCC compiler in Qt Creator Kit settings and GCC compiler used to build Qt installation have exactly the same versions.

Using `mingw64/share/qt6/mkspecs/qconfig.pri`, as suggested by ssbssa, I've got GCC version Qt installation was built with and supplied Qt Creator Kit with GCC compiler that have the same version. Now I see the warning is gone.